# Responsive image behaves differently in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, safari, cross-browser

I will provide screenshots for accurate solution, but if you want me to have the code in codepen and share the link too.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGgAgZ

Simply lets focus on the gray-scale image, it is wrapped by `.container-div` classed `div`.
This CSS behaves as expected in Chrome, Firefox but differently in Safari. 
I suppose it could be a problem of height, because in safari the image is taller than it is original size. Any solutions?

```
.container-div {
    float: right;
    width: 44.114583333333336%;
    height:auto;
    /*transform is prefixed correctly in the original CSS*/
    transform:translate(0%, 74%);

}
.container-div img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

This is Safari
[image: Safari]
This is Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Comment: can you please share a demo URL?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGgAgZ

Comment: When i added  `max-height:200%;` instead of  `max-height:100%;` the problem is solved now i see the images same in all browsers. That is a bit perplexing. How does safari treat `max-height` ? To any reviewers out there should i post this as an answer and close the question?